# extracting comments from facebook

Tags: java, facebook

I want to extract the details of persons who like a particular page. I'm trying it but now I'm trying to extract the comments/posts from a page based on the keyword I specify. I works but doesn't works good since only for some pages it shows output and shows some exceptions for all other keyword that I specify. Here is my sample code. How can I get the information abou users who liked a particular page?

```
Facebook facebook = new FacebookFactory().getInstance();
ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
facebook.setOAuthAppId("", "");
configurationBuilder
.setOAuthPermissions("id, name, first_name, last_name,likes");    

String  accessTokenString =  "*****";
AccessToken at = new AccessToken(accessTokenString);
configurationBuilder.setOAuthAppId("1466708753544336");
configurationBuilder.setOAuthAppSecret("*****");
facebook.setOAuthAccessToken(at);
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String s=sc.nextLine();
ResponseList<Post> posts=facebook.getPosts(s,new Reading().limit(100));
 StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    ResponseList<Post> res =facebook.getPosts(s);

    for(Post post :res)
    {
     //str.append(post.getMessage());
        for(int i=0;i<post.getComments().size();i++)
        {

             str.append(post.getComments().get(i).getMessage());
             str.append(post.getComments().get(i).getId());

         }
    }
     System.out.println(str);
}//try
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It shows this type of exception for some keywords when I enter "Ice-Cream". I don't know what's wrong with this. Any kind of help will be appreciated

```
Ice-Cream
FacebookException{statusCode=400, response=
HttpResponse{statusCode=400,  responseAsString='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//
W3C//DTD  XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xml:lang="en" lang="en" id="facebook">
<head>
<title>Facebook | Error</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
<meta name="robots"              content="noindex,nofollow" />
<style type="text/css">
  html, body {
    margin:       0px;
    padding:      0px;
    text-align:   center;
    font-family:  "Lucida Grande", "Tahoma", "Verdana", "Arial", sans-serif;
    color:        #333333;
  }

  a.menu {
    margin:     auto;
    position:   relative;
    display:    block;
    width:      964px;
    height:     29px;
    background: #3B5998 url('https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/common/error.png')
                top center no-repeat;
  }

  .core {
    text-align: left;
    margin:     auto;
    width:      904px;
    padding:    1em 0em;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size:  18px;
  }

  p {
    font-size:  13px;
  }

  .footer {
border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    color:      #777777;
    float:      left;
    width:      904px;
    padding:    5px 8px 6px 0;
    font-size:  11px;
  }
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  function back() {
    if (1 < history.length) {
      history.back();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="menu" href="http://www.facebook.com/"></a>
<div class="core">
  <h1>Sorry, something went wrong.</h1>
  <p>We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.</p>
  <p><a onclick="return back();" href="http://www.facebook.com/">Go Back</a></p>
  <div class="footer" id="pagefooter_copyright">
    Facebook &copy;
    2013
    &#183;
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/help/">Help</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
', is=sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection
$HttpInputStream@60e3907d, streamConsumed=true}, errorType='null',
errorMessage='null', errorCode=-1, errorSubcode=-1}
at facebook4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:189)
at facebook4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:65)
at facebook4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:93)
at facebook4j.FacebookImpl.get(FacebookImpl.java:2431)
at facebook4j.FacebookImpl.getPosts(FacebookImpl.java:691)
at facebook.NewTest.main(NewTest.java:41)
```

Comment: What's the exception and what are you entering?

Comment: @TedBigham I edited my ques and mentioned my i/p and exceptions

Comment: Is it possible that the dash is not a valid input character?

Comment: @TedBigham no if u check the same on facebook it shows like this..u can search other keywords too..it gives o/p for keywords chocolate,infosys etc not for others

Comment: okay. well the response page implies its a server error, but the 400 response code implies its a bad request.

Comment: @TedBigham but how can I fix it..can u help me for fixing it.Is there any other way

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48448/discussion-between-lulu-and-ted-bigham)